# Starting out with FourSquare Native Auth

Tags: php, foursquare

I am trying to dive in to the `FourSquare API` I created an app at `developers.foursquare.com` 
Now I am trying to get a login to work.

I am using this page as a starting point of reference.

[Click Here](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth)

This is the syntax it shows me for authenticating

```
    https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate
    ?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
    &response_type=code
    &redirect_uri=YOUR_REGISTERED_REDIRECT_URI
```

I am thinking this is where I would use `PHP To Do A http GET` ???

So should it be something like this?

```
      <?php
        $response = http_get("https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate", 
    array("?client_id=MyClientIdIsHere" ,"&response_type=code" , 
"&redirect_uri=http://www.MYRedirectURL"), $info);
        ?>
```

Also if anyone knows a shot in the direction of any tutorials for using foursquare I would appreciate it.

Is it all done with http request?